# Replace a single quotes only to a substring which has a pattern

Tags: java

I’m new to java and I have a string like this:

```
insert into table (name,data) values ('test',
'
<?xml>
<some>
    <tag>
    </tag>
</some>
<data>
    Here replace ' with ''
</data>
</xml>
'
)
```

Here I need to check only *within* the `<?xml></xml>` tag are there any `'` quotes available if so replace with `''`. How do I it Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Extract substring, 2. Check for single quotes, 3. Replace with double quotes. Which points have you achieved with which code and which points are to be corrected by us?

Comment: Substring the `<?xml>...<xml>` part & replace \\' with \\''

Comment: [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) or [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Note replaceAll uses regex so it is slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) methods to extract the specific part of the request you are looking for, and [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) to replace them:

```
private final static String XML_START_TAG = "<?xml>";
private final static String XML_END_TAG = "</xml>";

private static String doubleSqlQuote(String req) {
    if (req.contains(XML_START_TAG) && req.indexOf(XML_START_TAG) < req.lastIndexOf(XML_END_TAG)) {
        req = req.substring(0, req.indexOf(XML_START_TAG))
                + req.substring(req.indexOf(XML_START_TAG), req.lastIndexOf(XML_END_TAG)).replace("'", "''")
                + req.substring(req.lastIndexOf(XML_END_TAG));
    }
    return req;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String req = "insert into table (name,data) values ('test','<?xml><some><tag></tag></some><data>Here replace ' with ''</data></xml>')";
    System.out.println(doubleSqlQuote(req));
}
```

Result:

```
insert into table (name,data) values ('test','<?xml><some><tag></tag></some><data>Here replace '' with ''''</data></xml>')
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are trying to build a SQL insert statement that writes some data to the database and you realized that your statement breaks when there are quotes in the data.
The solution is: Don't build your statements this way. Use a prepared statement and provide the data as parameters. Saves you a lot of trouble.